# How To Find Elements In a List

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I need to **extract items** from a **List** as shown in the **working example below**.

I would like to avoid adding an additional

**or ('blah-blah' in data)**

for every instance I want to find.
Instead, i would like to shorten and simply this process to something like apple, berry, blah-blah as a single entry.

```
my_data = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'peach']
print(type(my_data))

all_instances = []

for data in my_data:
    if ('apple' in data) or ('berry' in data):
        all_instances.append(data)
print('All Instances Found:', all_instances)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if data in {'apple', 'berry'}`? I mean put the instances to be found in a set and then simply do `in set` or even better yet use set intersection

Comment: I think instead of checking if the input is in the data, you can check if the data is in the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have simple code, you can put all your desired input into a list and do list comparison.

```
my_data = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'peach']

input_ = ['apple','berry']

result = [i for i in my_data for j in input_ if j in i]
Out[436]: ['apple', 'strawberry']
```

Comment: I think @MarkWP needs `strawberry` to be in the result as well.

Comment: Ah my bad, thanks for noticing it. I will update it